# Python command-line application with setuptools alias problems

Tags: python, windows, setuptools

I have a Python command-line program that I am packaging with setuptools, in the manner of this article: https://gehrcke.de/2014/02/distributing-a-python-command-line-application/

In short, I'm using "console_scripts" to provide command-line functionality.  Unfortunately, for legacy reasons, the commands *must* be in the form of "command.py", instead of simply "command".

```
setup(
    ...
    entry_points = {
        "console_scripts": ['bootstrap.py = bootstrap.bootstrap:main']
        },
    ...
    )
```

The entry points work as expected on OSX:

```
% bootstrap.py
```

runs the bootstrap main() function.  All good.  However, on Windows the alias is automatically truncated to:

```
% bootstrap
```

Does anyone know of a way to circumvent this behavior and force Windows to use the "bootstrap.py" command?

Comment: setuptools should create bootstrap.py and bootstrap.exe in the Scripts directory. Finding this in `PATH` depends on your shell. In PowerShell a file extension has to be in `PATHEXT` to be found when searching `PATH`. In cmd, you don't *need* to add .PY to `PATHEXT`. It just lets cmd find the script without having to explicitly enter the .py file extension.

Comment: I *need* it to use the full command "bootstrap.py".  I don't care if "bootstrap" works as well.  This is for legacy/consistency reasons, and is not ideal. Nevertheless, that is the behavior I am looking for.

Comment: You're sure that it's not generating the .py script? The setuptools docs say it generates both the .py and .exe versions, but I'll grant you that documentation isn't exactly... reliable.

Comment: As far as I understand it, this syntax: ['bootstrap.py = bootstrap.bootstrap:main']  should mean that the alias 'bootstrap.py' calls the bootstrap main() function from the bootstrap module.  On Mac, this works -- "bootstrap.py" runs the bootstrap.main() function.  On Windows, it truncates to "bootstrap".  The alias *should* be arbitrary -- I can call it 'abcd' and have that run bootstrap.main().  It just doesn't allow the syntax of 'abcd.py'.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Is it creating the file "PythonXY\Scripts\bootstrap.py", or only creating "PythonXY\Scripts\bootstrap.exe"?

Comment: It is creating only \Scripts\bootstrap.exe.

Comment: With OSX, if my code has: ['bootstrap.py = bootstrap.bootstrap:main', 'bootstrap = bootstrap.bootstrap:main'], I get two files:  Python/.../bin/bootstrap and Python/.../bin/bootstrap.py.  Thus, on OSX I can use either alias: "bootstrap" or "bootstrap.py", but on Windows I can only use "bootstrap".